# I want to make an html form with the reset and copy to clipboard button,

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an html form with the reset and copy to clipboard button, without loosing the texts in the textbox while unchecking the checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to copy the content from an input:

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```